# How to trim Music Library file and save it document directry

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, core-audio

```
-(BOOL)trimAudioFileAtPath:(NSString *)inputFilename
                 start:(float)start
                   end:(float) stop{

           NSString *outputFilename = @"File Path";
           NSError *error = nil; NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager    defaultManager]; if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:outputFilename]) {

           if (![fileManager removeItemAtPath:outputFilename error:&error]) {

           DebugLog(@"error file remove:%@",error);    } else {
           DebugLog(@"sucess remove file");    
} }

       NSURL *audioFileInput = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:inputFilename]; 
       NSURL    *audioFileOutput = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:outputFilename];
       if (!audioFileInput || !audioFileOutput){    return NO; }
      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:audioFileOutput    error:NULL];

           AVMutableComposition *mutableComposition = [AVMutableComposition    composition]; // Create the video composition track.
           AVMutableCompositionTrack *mutableCompositionAudioTrack =    [mutableComposition addMutableTrackWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio    preferredTrackID:kCMPersistentTrackID_Invalid];
           NSLog(@"audioFileInput  %@",audioFileInput); AVURLAsset *assetUrl =    [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput];
           if ([[assetUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count]==0) {    return NO;  }

    // Get the first music track from each asset. AVAssetTrack *audioAssetTrack = [[assetUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] objectAtIndex:0]; [mutableCompositionAudioTrack insertTimeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(kCMTimeZero,audioAssetTrack.timeRange.duration) ofTrack:audioAssetTrack atTime:kCMTimeZero error:nil];

    // we need the audio asset to be at least 50 seconds long for this snippet

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(start, 1); 
    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake(stop, 1);
CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime,stopTime); 
Float64 duration = CMTimeGetSeconds(exportTimeRange.duration);

// Create the export session with the composition and set the preset to the highest quality. 
AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:mutableComposition presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

if (duration > 6.0){

    AVMutableAudioMix *mutableAudioMix = [AVMutableAudioMix audioMix];
    // Create the audio mix input parameters object.
    AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters *mixParameters = [AVMutableAudioMixInputParameters audioMixInputParametersWithTrack:mutableCompositionAudioTrack];

    // float totalDutaion=mutableComposition.duration.value;
    float totalDutaion=duration;
    float lenth=totalDutaion/3;
    CMTime startCM = CMTimeMake(totalDutaion-lenth-1,mutableComposition.duration.timescale);
    CMTime endCM = CMTimeMake(lenth, mutableComposition.duration.timescale);

    // Set the volume ramp to slowly fade the audio out over the duration of the composition.
    [mixParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:0.f toEndVolume:1.f timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(startTime, endCM)];
    [mixParameters setVolumeRampFromStartVolume:1.f toEndVolume:0.f timeRange:CMTimeRangeMake(startCM,endCM)];

    // Attach the input parameters to the audio mix.
    mutableAudioMix.inputParameters = @[mixParameters];
    exportSession.audioMix=mutableAudioMix; }

if (exportSession == nil){

    return NO; }


exportSession.outputURL = audioFileOutput; exportSession.outputFileType = AVFileTypeAppleM4A; exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;

[exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^  {
     if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted == exportSession.status)
     {
         // It worked!
     }
     else if (AVAssetExportSessionStatusFailed == exportSession.status)
     {
         // It failed...
     }  }]; return YES; }
```

I am using this function to trim the music file from music libaray. The Above code is working file when I try to trim a file which is located in bundle. But When I try to use the same function with input file from iTune music Library it is give no Tracks i.e.    if ([[assetUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count]==0) {
        return NO;
    } return No. Can anyone help to trim music from iTunes Libaray

Comment: How are you getting the file from the iTunes Library?

Comment: @Dave Please see the code below

Answer (score 0):

```
- (void) mediaPicker: (MPMediaPickerController *) mediaPicker didPickMediaItems: (MPMediaItemCollection *) mediaItemCollection
{
    if (mediaItemCollection) {
        NSLog(@"%@",[mediaItemCollection items]);
       // [musicPlayer setQueueWithItemCollection: mediaItemCollection];
       // [musicPlayer play];
    }

    [KVNProgress showWithStatus:@"Processing"];

    MPMediaItem *item =mediaItemCollection.representativeItem;
    NSURL* assetURL = [item valueForProperty:MPMediaItemPropertyAssetURL];


    // set up an AVAssetReader to read from the iPod Library
    AVURLAsset *songAsset =
    [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:assetURL options:nil];

    NSError *assetError = nil;
    AVAssetReader *assetReader =[AVAssetReader assetReaderWithAsset:songAsset error:&assetError];
    if (assetError) {
        NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
        return;
    }


    AVAssetReaderOutput *assetReaderOutput =[AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput assetReaderAudioMixOutputWithAudioTracks:songAsset.tracks
      audioSettings: nil];

    if (! [assetReader canAddOutput: assetReaderOutput]) {
        NSLog (@"can't add reader output... die!");
        return;
    }
    [assetReader addOutput: assetReaderOutput];


//    NSArray *dirs = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains
//              (NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
//    NSString *documentsDirectoryPath = [dirs objectAtIndex:0];
//    NSString *exportPath = [documentsDirectoryPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"out.m4a"];
    NSString * exportPath =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", NSTemporaryDirectory(), @"out.m4a"];


    if ([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:exportPath]) {

        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:exportPath
                                                   error:nil];
    }
    NSURL *exportURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:exportPath];

    AVAssetWriter *assetWriter =[AVAssetWriter assetWriterWithURL:exportURL
                              fileType:AVFileTypeCoreAudioFormat
                                 error:&assetError];
    if (assetError) {
        NSLog (@"error: %@", assetError);
        return;
    }


    AudioChannelLayout channelLayout;
    memset(&channelLayout, 0, sizeof(AudioChannelLayout));
    channelLayout.mChannelLayoutTag = kAudioChannelLayoutTag_Stereo;
    NSDictionary *outputSettings =[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   @(kAudioFormatLinearPCM), AVFormatIDKey,
                                   @44100.0, AVSampleRateKey,
                                   @2, AVNumberOfChannelsKey,
                                   [NSData dataWithBytes:&channelLayout length:sizeof(AudioChannelLayout)],AVChannelLayoutKey,
                                   @16, AVLinearPCMBitDepthKey,
                                   @NO, AVLinearPCMIsNonInterleaved,
                                   @NO,AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey,
                                   @NO, AVLinearPCMIsBigEndianKey,
                                   nil];

    AVAssetWriterInput *assetWriterInput =[AVAssetWriterInput assetWriterInputWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio
                                        outputSettings:outputSettings];
    if ([assetWriter canAddInput:assetWriterInput]) {
        [assetWriter addInput:assetWriterInput];
    } else {
        NSLog (@"can't add asset writer input... die!");
        return;
    }
    assetWriterInput.expectsMediaDataInRealTime = NO;


    [assetWriter startWriting];
    [assetReader startReading];
    AVAssetTrack *soundTrack = [songAsset.tracks objectAtIndex:0];
    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake (0, soundTrack.naturalTimeScale);
    [assetWriter startSessionAtSourceTime: startTime];


    __block UInt64 convertedByteCount = 0;
    dispatch_queue_t mediaInputQueue =
    dispatch_queue_create("mediaInputQueue", NULL);
    [assetWriterInput requestMediaDataWhenReadyOnQueue:mediaInputQueue
                                            usingBlock: ^
     {
         while (assetWriterInput.readyForMoreMediaData) {
             CMSampleBufferRef nextBuffer =
             [assetReaderOutput copyNextSampleBuffer];
             if (nextBuffer) {
                 // append buffer
                 [assetWriterInput appendSampleBuffer: nextBuffer];
                 // update ui
                 convertedByteCount +=
                 CMSampleBufferGetTotalSampleSize (nextBuffer);


             } else {
                 // done!
                 [assetWriterInput markAsFinished];
                 [assetWriter finishWritingWithCompletionHandler:^{

                     [assetReader cancelReading];
                     [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateCompletedAtMusicPath:)
                                            withObject:exportPath
                                         waitUntilDone:NO];

                   //  NSLog (@"done. file size is %llu",[outputFileAttributes fileSize]);
                 }];
                 break;
             }}}];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:NO completion:^{

    }];
}
```

This is code used for geting the URL form iTune Library and story in document directry

Comment: the above code working fine but When I try to use the Path it will give nil track. i.e. if ([[assetUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count]==0) { return NO; }

Comment: So, to make sure I understand your process, you are reading the entire audio file from your music library and writing it to your documents directory, then you are attempting to write a portion of that file to a third file. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes Correct! like dubsmash App

Comment: Our main Aim is to select the music form iTune Library then trim that selected song and mix that song with Video

Answer (score 0):

First i just want to point out that you can just read segments of the audio from the library by setting the timeRange property of your assetReader.  This way instead of copying over the whole file first you can just copy the segments you need. That being said, if you are going to stick with your original implementation,  i think you just need to change `AVURLAsset *assetUrl = [AVURLAsset assetWithURL:audioFileInput];` to `AVURLAsset *assetUrl = [[AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:audioFileInput options:nil];`

Comment: still getting 0 in if ([[assetUrl tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio] count]==0) {
        return NO;
    }

Comment: Have you verified that the audio saved to disk is valid by playing it? Try pulling the file from your app bundle and playing it. If you have a valid audio file with the correct URL then all you need to do is this `AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc]initWithURL:fileURL options:nil];`
`NSArray *tracks = [asset tracksWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeAudio];`

Comment: file is save in disk but not playing. Suppose if we didn't save the audio file how we mix that with video???

Comment: here sample code can you please review it and send it back https://www.dropbox.com/s/fqgzwouieundyfn/VideoFilter.zip?dl=0

Comment: @Girijesh Kumar If you have another question, ask another question.

Comment: I mean you should start a new thread by articulating a new question instead of carrying on with comments to an unrelated question.  This way someone looking for the same information will have an easier time finding it.

Answer (score 0):

I Got sucess to save itune music in document libray by using following Method

```
NSArray* paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString* documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
self.fullPathToFileForAudio = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"auto-old.m4a"];

        NSFileManager *fileMgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

        // get rid of existing mp4 if exists...
        if ([fileMgr removeItemAtPath:self.fullPathToFileForAudio error:&error] != YES)
            NSLog(@"Unable to delete file: %@", [error localizedDescription]);


        [self convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:self.musicUrl outputURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.fullPathToFileForAudio] handler:^(AVAssetExportSession *exportSession)
         {
             if (exportSession.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatusCompleted)
             {
                 NSLog(@"completed %@",exportSession.error);

                 printf("completed\n");


                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

                     NSLog(@"%@ PATH",self.fullPathToFileForAudio);
                     [self exporterCompleted:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:self.fullPathToFileForAudio]];
                 });
             }
             else
             {
                 //  NSLog(@"%@",exportSession.error);
                 printf("error\n");

                 dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                     [SVProgressHUD dismiss];
                 });

             }
         }];



- (void)convertVideoToLowQuailtyWithInputURL:(NSURL*)inputURL
                                   outputURL:(NSURL*)outputURL
                                     handler:(void (^)(AVAssetExportSession*))handler
{
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:outputURL error:nil];
    AVURLAsset *asset = [AVURLAsset URLAssetWithURL:inputURL options:nil];
    AVAssetExportSession *exportSession = [[AVAssetExportSession alloc] initWithAsset:asset presetName:AVAssetExportPresetAppleM4A];

    CMTime startTime = CMTimeMake(minValue, 1);
    CMTime stopTime = CMTimeMake(maxValue, 1);
    CMTimeRange exportTimeRange = CMTimeRangeFromTimeToTime(startTime, stopTime);

    exportSession.outputURL = outputURL;
    exportSession.outputFileType = @"com.apple.m4a-audio";
    exportSession.timeRange = exportTimeRange;

    [exportSession exportAsynchronouslyWithCompletionHandler:^(void)
     {
         handler(exportSession);

     }];
}
```